# Code Profiling with frequent restarts

Tags: profiling

I'm looking for a code profiler which is somewhat tolerant of the fact that our application starts and stops rather frequently.

In other words, suppose my application is:

```
int main()
{
    ConfigType config =  WaitToBeConfigured(); 
    SetUpThreadsAndRun(config); 
    return 1; 
}
```

We'd like to get some idea of the line/function coverage of the several hundred functions under SetupThreadsAndRun().

The walls we've hit with profilers:

- Most profiling tools I've seen require the application to terminate "normally" (i.e. that return 1 is hit and you follow the program's post-main routine to write out the stats file).  In my case our application is structured such that it never exits unless you terminate with an exit() or reboot.
- We're going to be starting/stopping several times as we switch configurations, and would like a summary report of all the runs (i.e. of the 50 or so possible configurations we'd like to know if any functions or lines are not being covered). If we can solve (1) I might be able to handle this with a perl script.

Any thoughts on how we might proceed? We're looking mostly for line coverage (not memory or speed).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no currently supported to do this... the best option was to refactor our application to make it exit cleanly.